# Are C++ vector constructors efficient?

Tags: c++, vector, constructor

If I make a vector like this:

```
vector<int>(50000000, 0);
```

What happens internally? Does it make a default vector and then continually add values, resizing as necessary? Note: 50,000,000 is not known at compile time.

Would it make a difference if I make the vector like this:

```
gVec = vector<int>(); 
gVec.reserve(50000000);
// push_back default values
```

Please tell me the constructor knows to avoid unnecessary reallocations given the two parameters.

Comment: the guys that designed the standard library are extremely clever, it would've been a shame to design the vector ctor with multiple allocations ;) so the answer is no, it allocates in one go

Comment: @vsoftco - it's part of the standard that `vector` elements are stored contiguously.

Comment: @SteveTownsend correct, however, you can still do it in steps: new memory, delete memory, new 2*memory etc, which makes absolutely no sense.

Answer (score 3):

> Would it make a difference if I make the vector like this:
>
> ```
> gVec = vector<int>(); 
> gVec.reserve(50000000);
> // push_back default values
> ```

Yes it definitiely makes a difference Using `push_back()` to fill in the default values may turn out a lot less efficient.
To have the same operations as with done with the constructor `vector<int>(50000000, 0);` use [**`std::vector<int>::resize()`**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize):

```
vector<int> gVec; 
gVec.resize(50000000,0);
```

Answer (score 3):

You will greatly enhance what you learn from this question by stepping through the two options in the debugger - seeing what the `std::vector` source code does should be instructive if you can mentally filter out a lot of the initially-confusing template and memory allocation abstractions. Demystify this for yourself - the STL is just someone else's code, and most of my work time is spent looking through that.

`std::vector` guarantees contiguous storage so only one memory block is ever allocated for the elements.  The `vector` control structure will require a second allocation, if it is heap-based and not RAII (stack-based).

`vector<int>(N, 0);`

creates a vector of `capacity` >= N and `size` N, with N values each set to `0`.

Step by step:

`gVec = vector<int>();`

creates an empty vector, typically with a nominal 'best-guess' `capacity`.

`gVec.reserve(N);`

updates the vector's `capacity` - ensures the vector has room for at least N elements. Typically this involves a reallocation from the 'best guess' default `capacity`, which is unlikely to be large enough for the value of N proposed in this question.

`// push_back default values`

Each iteration here increases the vector's `size` by one and sets the new `back()` element of the vector  to `0`.  The vector's `capacity` will not change until the number of values pushed exceeds `N plus whatever pad the vector implementation might have applied` (typically none).

Comment: I like that you mentioned the difference between `size` and `capacity` which, although I feel was not directly related to the question, I also felt would be very helpful for a beginner to begin to understand the question (that the `vector` class is implemented with `size` and `capacity`). I also found the part about 'best-guess' capacity intriguing. However, from a previous question, I understand that according to the Standard, `reserve` only needs to inform the `vector` of a change in size and not necessarily perform any allocation(until perhaps an element is added). Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 2):

`reserve` solely allocates storage. No initialization is performed. Applied on an empty `vector` it should result in one call to the `allocate` member function of the allocator used.

The constructor shown allocates the storage required **and initializes every element to zero**: It's semantically equivalent to a `reserve` and a row of `push_back`'s.

In both cases no reallocations are done.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose in theory the constructor *could* start by allocating a small block of memory and expanding several times before returning, at least for types that didn't have side-effects in their copy constructor. This would be allowed only because there were no observable side effects of doing so though, not because the standard does anything to allow it directly.

At least in my opinion, it's not worth spending any time or effort worrying about such a possibility though. Chances of anybody doing it seem remote, to say the least. It's only "allowed" to the degree that it's essentially impossible to truly prohibit it.